# What is the general solution to split strings inside strings in order to get a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, multidimensional-array

How to implement a split string functions that can split strings inside strings recursively? It should be look like:

Return a 0d array (original string):

```
var arr=mySplit('a',[]);
//arr='a'
```

Return a 1D array:

```
var arr=mySplit('a|b',['|']);
//arr=['a','b']
```

Return a 2D array:

```
var arr=mySplit('a,1|b,2',['|',',']);
//arr=[['a','1'],['b','2']]
```

Return a 3D array:

```
var arr=mySplit('a:A,1:One|b:B,2:Two',['|',',',':']);
//arr=[[['a','A'],['1','One']],[['b','B'],['2','Two']]]
```

I tried to implement from 0d to 2d individually:

0D:

```js
var split0d=function(str,sep){
    return str;
}
document.write(split0d('a',[]));
```

1D:

```js
var split1d=function(str,sep){
    let result=[];
    result=str.split(sep[0]);
    return result;
}
document.write(split1d('a|b',['|']));
```

2D:

```js
var split2d=function(str,sep){
    let result=[];
    
    let arr1=str.split(sep[0]);
    for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
        result.push(arr1[i].split(sep[1]));
    }

    return result;
}
document.write(split2d('a,1|b,2|c,3',['|',',']));
```

but I still have no idea how to implement the general solution of this question because the codes for 0D to 2D looks very different for me. How to I achieve the general solutions of splitting strings inside strings recursively?

Comment: post the expected resulting arrays for each of the above cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map` for the loop and then let the callback make the recursive call. `slice` will make sure the used separator is not passed on to the recursive call. When there are no more delimiters, the second argument will be an empty array, and in that case the string should be returned as-is:

```js
function mySplit(s, sep) {
    return sep.length ? s.split(sep[0]).map( s => mySplit(s, sep.slice(1)) ) : s;
}

// Sample call
const result = mySplit('a:A,1:One|b:B,2:Two',['|',',',':']);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have to admit, I've spend so much time thinking about linear iterative process that I couldn't remember how to design the recursive process. Perfect encoding. A+

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is the right idea.

> but I still have no idea how to implement the general solution of this question because the codes for 0D to 2D looks very different for me.

OK, then let's rewrite them a bit:

```
function split1d(str1, sep) {
    let result1 = [];
    let arr1 = str1.split(sep[0]);
    for (let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
        let str2 = arr[i];
        result1.push(str2);
    }
    return result1;
}

function split2d(str2, sep) {
    let result2 = [];
    let arr2 = str2.split(sep[0]);
    for (let j=0; j<arr2.length; j++) {
        let str1 = arr[j];
        let result1 = [];
        let arr1 = str1.split(sep[1]);
        for (let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
            let str0 = arr1[i];
            result1.push(str0);
        }
        result2.push(result1);
    }
    return result2;
}
```

How about similarities now?

Of course the whole thing gets a lot easier to spot when using the [Array `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
function split0d(str0, sep) {
    return str0;
}
function split1d(str1, sep) {
    return str1.split(sep[0]).map(str0 => str0);
}
function split2d(str2, sep) {
    return str2.split(sep[0]).map(str1 => str1.split(sep[1]).map(str0 => str0));
}
```

You can see how this becomes

```
function split0d(str0, sep) {
    return str0;
}
function split1d(str1, sep) {
    return str1.split(sep[0]).map(str0 => split0d(str0, sep.slice(1)));
}
function split2d(str2, sep) {
    return str2.split(sep[0]).map(str1 => split1d(str0, sep.slice(1)));
}
```

And making that into a generic recursive function that checks `sep.length` should be simple now.

Comment: Very nice exhibition of pattern

Answer (score 0):

Will map and recursion work?

```js
var mySplit = (str,sep)=>{
  const recur = (all,sep)=>
    (sep.length===0)
      ? all
      : all.split(sep[0]).map(item=>recur(item,sep.slice(1)));
  return recur(str,sep);
}
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    mySplit('a:A,1:One|b:B,2:Two',['|',',',':']),
    undefined,
    2
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do as follows;

```js
var splitND = (ss,[d,...ds]) => d ? ss.split(d)
                                      .map(s => splitND(s,ds))
                                  : ss,
    result  = splitND('a:A,1:One|b:B,2:Two',['|',',',':']);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```